# zsh some unicode input shown as code in angle brackets in prompt line (but not output)

Tags: zsh, unicode

In my cygwin / mintty setup, when I have the unicode characters and U+1F60C ( relieved face) in my Windows clipboard, type `echo '`, paste, type `'` and enter, zsh displays it as inverse video `<d83d><de0c>` in the prompt line, but the output shows the desired character. Doing the same with character U+263A (☺ white smiling face) looks okay both in the prompt line and output.

I have read ["Chapter 5: Multibyte input and output"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq05.html) which mentions the angle bracket notation in combination with the `COMBINING_CHARS` option. But toggling that option did not help.

This is not just a cosmetic issue. It breaks what I actually want to achieve: Look up the name of emoticons which to my eyes are hard to read: I created a list by installing package unicode-ucd and prefixing each line with the actual character:

```
> bash -c 'while IFS= read -r l || [ -s "$l" ]; do c=${l%;*}; echo -en "\\U$c"; echo ";$l"; done' < /usr/share/unicode/ucd/UnicodeData.txt > /tmp/unicode-list.txt
```

Then I would like to search it, for example with command `grep -Fa -m 1 -- '☺' /tmp/unicode-list.txt` (which works) or `grep -Fa -m 1 -- '' /tmp/unicode-list.txt` (which gets replaced with `grep -Fa -m 1 -- '<d83d><de0c>' /tmp/unicode-list.txt` and does not work).

What's going on here, and how can I make zsh show the character and pass it to commands correctly?

Environment:

```
> locale; echo; o=$(uname -a) && echo "${o//$(hostname)/...}"; echo; cygcheck -c zsh mintty unicode-ucd
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

CYGWIN_NT-10.0 ... 3.1.4(0.340/5/3) 2020-02-19 08:49 x86_64 Cygwin

Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
mintty               3.1.4-1        OK
unicode-ucd          10.0.0-1       OK
zsh                  5.5.1-1        OK
```